# Dockerfile with custom parent image

Tags: docker, http, dockerfile

How can I use existing images as the `FROM` parameter in a dockerfile?

I'm trying to dockerize a VueJS application, but wanted [pierrezemb/gostatic](https://hub.docker.com/r/pierrezemb/gostatic) to be the base image -- it's a tiny http server that, in principle, is able to host files and directories. However, when running the completed image and checking the exposed port in the browser, the `index.html` file loads but all other resources in subfolders 404 fail with:
`The resource from “http://localhost:8043/js/app.545bfbc1.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)`. Curling the resource returns just the 404.

This is likely because the gostatic base image is created to be very much standalone, not to be included as the `FROM` parameter in a Dockerfile. When I build the code myself and use gostatic to host the directory, everything is fine. When I build with a Dockerfile, build succeeds but I get the aforementioned errors when trying to get resources not in the main directory.

Ideal, standalone use case:

```sh
docker run -d -p 80:8043 -v path/to/website:/srv/http --name goStatic pierrezemb/gostatic
```

Current Dockerfile

```
FROM pierrezemb/gostatic AS deployment

COPY ./dist/* /srv/http/
EXPOSE 8043

# Note, gostatic calls: ENTRYPOINT ["/goStatic"]
# Therefore CMD need only be goStatic parameters
CMD ["-enable-health", "-enable-logging"]
```

Note, dist folder is built and functioning. Also notably, the health endpoint doesn't work, and there is no logging (which the flags are set for). It's clear I'm handling the parent image wrong

I'm building and running with the following commands:

```sh
docker build -t tweet-dash .
docker run -d -p 8043:8043 --name dash tweet-dash
```

Dockerfile for goStatic is [here](https://github.com/PierreZ/goStatic/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually almost exactly the way you're supposed to use existing images: everything here is being done correctly.

For those coming after; pay attention to the parent base image's Dockerfile -- build your own with it open next to you. Figure out how to use the image by itself, as a standalone first, and then see if you can add on to it.

The Dockerfile is slightly incorrect in this case: when you copy a file directory over with `COPY ./dist/* /srv/http`, docker will iterate recursively over file structure and add each individual file to `/srv/http`. No folders will be preserved.

This can be fixed by doing `COPY ./dist /srv/http`.